# Save changed data to database

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7

In my app i am taking data from server in json format and making some changes in my data.i am able to download and save data in my app.But I am unable to post the data into the server.
I am using SQLITE and ASIHTTP from this operation.I want to save data on server on Submit Button click.

Any help for saving data into the server.Thanks

Comment: Please check my updated answer, I have a link to an excellent tutorial on creating what I am talking about below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to achieve what you want is to create a PHP based API on your server, call the API with post data containing the payload you want to save.

Once you have the post data on the server you can use PHP to parse out the information and inject it into a local database.

[Tutorial...](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2941/how-to-write-a-simple-phpmysql-web-service-for-an-ios-app)

To actually call the PHP API in your Objective C source on iOS I suggest using AFNetworking a nice networking framework for iOS: [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/tree/1.x/Example) (This has recently been updated to version 2.0, and the framework has changed slightly, in this example I've linked to the 1.x version and this class only exists in that version).

You can use the **AFHTTPClient** class.

Assuming your instance of AFHTTPClient is called:

```
AFHTTPClient *client;
```

Then use it like this:

First create a dictionary containing your PHP API Parameters, e.g. your API command, and any data you want to pass up to the server:

```
NSDictionary *params = @{@"cmd":@"uploadData",
                           @"dataToUpload":[_dataModel someData],
                           @"someOtherDataToUpload":[_dataModel someOtherData]};
```

Then call the post function on the client like this. Note: it has completion blocks that will be called for success or failure.

```
    [self.client postPath:@"/api.php" 
                            parameters:params 
                            success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

         //Success block call back (do some code here, 
         //update UI to say upload complete)
    }
    failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
         //Upload failed... Do some UI update here also maybe?      

    }
```

The rest you just do in PHP on your web server.

Comment: Actually its done.I want some code snippet to send data to the server.As there are many data field.